# how to replace string in SpEL expression?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

firstly,thanks for attention
i defined ftp adapter in my spring integration project and used `mv` command to move files in ftp server,directory structure is:
ftp-root
-----------Directory1\
-----------------in\
---------------------------file.in
-----------------out\

i want to move file `file.in` in `ftp-root\Directory1\in\` directory to move `ftp-root\Directory1\out\` with `.out.rpt`  extension `ftp-root\Directory1\out\a.out`
i used `int-ftp:outbound-gateway` adapter to run `mv` command on ftp server,my code is:

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayMv"
                          session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                          expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename"
                          request-channel="mvChannel"
                          command="mv"
                          rename-expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename "
                          reply-channel="aggregateResultsChannel"/>
```

how to use SpEL expression to replace `in` with `out` in rename-expression option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rename-expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename.replaceFirst('in', 'out')"
```

In most cases SpEL work like the regular Java. Since `filename` is a `String` you can apply for it any string operation.

Comment: i set it but thrown bellow exception:
`org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 49): Method call: Method relaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be found on java.lang.String type`

Comment: i set to filename-pattern to `"*.in"` in ls command, but return empty list , expected `file.in` what is your idea ?

Comment: Separate question? No ? Please, conclude us that we have to answer to this question here, not from separate SO thread. But, please, read documentation first of all. Spring Integration as well as FTP for the `LS` command.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for @Artem Bilan ane @Gary for answer
the other way to working with string 
define a bean as bellow :

```
public class StringUtil {
    public String replacement(String value,String var1,String var2) {
        return value.replace(var1,var2);
    }
}
```

and in expression option set to:

```
rename-expression="@stringUtil.replacement(payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename,'in','out')"
```