# sftp:outbound-gateway moving file not working

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to spring-integration. I request to help me with this issue.

I am using sftp:outbound-gateway to move a file from one folder to another folder.

Folder structure is:

```
top-dir
- module-dir
    - output-dir
        filexyz.txt
    - archive-dir
```

I want to move filexyz.txt from output to archive folder.

Configuration is:

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway 
session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename"
request-channel="inChannel"
command="mv"
rename-expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' +      
payload.filename.replaceFirst('output-dir','archive-dir')"
reply-channel="outChannel"/>
```

java code:

```
 DirectChannel moveChannel = context.getBean("inChannel",DirectChannel.class);
 moveChannel.send(new GenericMessage<File>(new File("top-dir\module-dir\output-dir\filexyz.txt")));
```

I referred issue at [how to replace string in SpEL expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790624/how-to-replace-string-in-spel-expression) but could not solve my problem.

I am getting Expression evaluation failed: payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename exception.

I think I am doing something wrong in java code.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> `expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename"`

Your payload is a simple `java.io.File`; it does not have those properties.

You need to use the absolute path; something like

`expression="payload.absolutePath`

and

`rename-expression="payload.absolutePath.replace....`

If you are running on windows you might also need to replace `\` with `/` too.

To use your existing expressions, you need a custom payload instead of `File`, with `remoteDirectory` and `filename` properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary. I could solve the issue with custom payload.